# Counting all subsequences constrained to a condition

Tags: algorithms, counting

I was trying to find all subsequences constrained to the following conditions:

1. remove element from the end.
2. remove element from the beginning.
3. remove element from both sides.

For example, given the sequence $(1,2,3,4)$ have subsequences $\{(1,2,3,4), (1,2,3), (1,2), (1), (2,3,4), (2,3), (2), (3,4), (3), (4)\}$. So, we have get total 10 subsequences.

**Attempt**: I was thinking of using combinators ${N}\choose{i}$, where $N$ is the length of subsequence in our case and $i$ is the limit boundary of subsequence that starts at $i=1$ and increase all the way to $N-1$. However, since jumps are not allowed, this approach does not seem valid as it will count subsequence like $(1,3,4)$ which is not allowed.

Can you think of an hint/approach based on combinators/permutations to solve this please if possible or this can only be solved iteratively (through for loops/recursion)?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, you are counting the number of continuous subsequences. Every continuous subsequence one-to-one corresponds to a pair of positions representing its start position and end position, so the total number is $\binom{N}{2}$.